# Download Files with FTP using conditional stament

Tags: c#

Here is the Solution ,thanks Gustavo for the suggestion:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConsoleApplication1.Program test = new Program();
        string Name = "SE_TEST";
        string[] filteredfiles = test.GetFileList();
        string[] files = filteredfiles;
    foreach (string file in files)
    {

        bool b;
        if (b = file.Contains(Name))
        {
            test.Download(file);

        }
    }
    }
    public string[] GetFileList()
    {
        string[] downloadFiles;
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        WebResponse response = null;
        StreamReader reader = null;
        try
        {
            FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
            reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + "1.0.0.1" + "/"));
            reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
            reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("sh", "SE");
            reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
            reqFTP.Proxy = null;
            reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;
            reqFTP.UsePassive = false;
            response = reqFTP.GetResponse();
            reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            while (line != null)
            {
                result.Append(line);
                result.Append("\n");
                line = reader.ReadLine();
            }
            // to remove the trailing '\n'
            result.Remove(result.ToString().LastIndexOf('\n'), 1);
            return result.ToString().Split('\n');
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (reader != null)
            {
                reader.Close();
            }
            if (response != null)
            {
                response.Close();
            }                
            downloadFiles = null;
            return downloadFiles;
        }
    }

    private void Download(string file)
    {                       

        try
        {
            FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
            string ftpserverIp = "1.0.0.1";

            string fileName = @"c:\downloadDir\" + file;
            FileInfo downloadFile = new FileInfo(fileName);
            // string uri = "ftp://1.0.0.1";
             FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Append);
             reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + ftpserverIp + "/" + file));
            reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
            reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;
            reqFTP.Timeout = -1;
            reqFTP.UsePassive = true;
            reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("sh", "SE");
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
            Stream ftpStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            long cl = response.ContentLength;
           // reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
            int bufferSize = 4096;
            int readCount;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            Console.WriteLine("Connected: Downloading File");
            while (readCount > 0)
            {
                outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
                readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                Console.WriteLine(readCount.ToString());
            }

            ftpStream.Close();
            outputStream.Close();
            response.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Downloading Complete");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex);
        }

    }
    }
}
```

It works as expected but not sure about the performance,is this any better way to do please suggest.Anyway thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- List all files with the method:
  [`WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229716.aspx)
- Filter FileNames with [`Contains()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dy85x1sa.aspx)
- Download ALL the Files that Contains your string.

Comment: thanks Gustavo, you mean like that  reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;